# Phase co-existence and Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Accoring to Callen's "Themodynamics and introduction to thermostatistics", second edition, page 157, the principle of minimum Gibbs free energy states:

> The equilibrium value of any unconstrained internal parameter in a system in contact with a thermal and pressure resevoir minimises the Gibbs potential at constant temperature and pressure.

Now consider following graph showing $g=\frac{G}{N}$ as a function of $v$ (volume per particle) for a Van der Waals gas (consider the black curve, which is donde for $T>T_c$):
[image]
This function has two minima, one corresponding to the volume of a liquid, and the other corresponding to the volume of a gas. If a system had a mixture of both phases, $v$ would take a value in the between the two minima, so $g$ would not be minimum and the system would not be at equilibrium. However I know that phases can coexist at equilibrium so, what is the problem with my explanation?

Comment: You are confusing the volume of your container and the volume of a particle in each phase. The stable phases are the tie line between the two minima, and the ratio of phases present will depend on how many particles you have and the volume of the container.

Comment: the kind of tie line @JonCuster is talking about is on page 205 in Callen's book where on Figure 8.2 the entropy (instead of G) is plotted.

Comment: So the real $G$ is the function plotted above, but replacing the section in between the minima with the straight line that connects them? @hyportnex

Comment: Yes, that is correct and at equilibrium the point on the connecting line between the two G minima represents the coexistence of two phases in which each phase corresponds to one of the two minima. See further details in section 9-5.